# $p$-volume of $n$-dimensional hyper-ellipsoids

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I read that the unit hypersphere has maximum volume for dimension five and would like to generalize this result.  (If you think that integrating over an $n$-dimensional $p$-hyper-ellipsoid area ($x_1^p+x_2^p+...+x_n^p=1$) is too trivial for MathOverflow, delete.)

*Mathematica* gave the complicated result:

$$\frac{\Gamma(1 + p^{-1})^2}{\Gamma((2 + p)/p)} + {}_2F_1(-p^{-1}, p^{-1}, 1 + p^{-1}, {(-1)}^p)$$

which could be wrong by a factor 2.  Thus even for $n=2$ the Gaussian integrals show the result is not elementary.

Comment: Don't you mean "surface area" of hypereggs?

Comment: I really don't understand what the question is...

Comment: I read it as asking how to determine, given $p$, which dimension yields the maximum hypersurface area.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I think the OP might mean the hyper-volume of the solid egg, not the hyper-area of its surface. (Because for $p=2$, the unit ball in $n$-space achieves its maximal volume for $n=5$, but does not achieve its maximal surface area until $n=7$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#/media/File:N_SpheresVolumeAndSurfaceArea.png)

Comment: @WillBrian I didn't check the numbers, and I trust you are correct, but if so I find that the wording is very confusing.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the problem was integrating over a "Bereich", as you say in Germany. "Area" wasn't very clever as I mean the volume indeed. "Area" is the "official" translation, though! :-(